# Servicestack POST - 413 request entity is too large

Tags: servicestack

I have a rather large object graph (84Kb) that I'm POSTing to a Servicestack service - the web server is returning a 413 - "Request Entity is too large".  I have seen various solutions on setting up a binding for WCF services that can override this value, I'm wondering how to configure this in ServiceStack services.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are always limits inherent in IIS/ASP.NET and never in ServiceStack which doesn't add any additional usage limits itself.

The solution then depends on the version of IIS/ASP.NET you're using, e.g. fix for IIS 6.0:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx

Comment: we found this suggested fix after posting this question, and it appears to have fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use servicestack behing Nginx, check your server config:

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```